# Java application show PKIX path building failed when calling external api

Tags: java, api, ssl

My application is running for fetch data from a website with https:
let say
https://api.something.com

When I call with Apache HttpClient using HttpClients.createDefault();

It return the above error show PKIX path building failed.

Even I use Postman to call the api. I still need to disable SSL certification verification to make the call success.

My question is:

1. Is this is a one way ssl verification? because I don't post data to that domain. I only pull data from it. So server don't have to know who I am. But I can know that's exactly the server I call, and api response is from that domain as well (no middle man). Is my concept correct?
2. So to resolve this problem, can I just use a dummy sslContext?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it may be one way `TLS` but you should have the certificate of CA that issued the certificate of your server in your trust store in java (or other client) to have `SSL` connection.

Comment: thanks, Yes, the call is success when I used dummySSLContext. But I don't know if this is a practice to make one way ssl verification.

Comment: In some situation there is no problem in one way `SSL` if you don't want to verify your client using certificate. it strongly depends on your application.

Comment: Yes, in my situation, it's one way ssl. So may I ask one more question: Even I use dummy ssl context to make request, is it still a secure connection? Because I called a website that used https protocol. If yes, I guess it's okay to use dummy SSL because I can still verify the data is exactly from that site.

Comment: Yes, I am a client calling server. so I have no idea why the server still need my cert. it's weird. Or in order to make a secure connection. my cert is still needed. but verify my cert or not is depend on the server. So in my situation, even I use dummy ssl, it can still pass because server don't care my cert is valid or not. if server cares, my request should be rejected, am I right?

Comment: Yes data is encrypted and no one can read your data passing by, but the important thing is that you can't verify that the server is the one who he claims, you should get their certificate in a secure way or you should have their CA certificate in your trust store.